# JQuery. get doesnt call on server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery to call a method which load a partial page onto a hidden div,
on the local machine this method works fine,   but when i add the code to the server the partial page does not load. any ideas why this doesn't work

```
var url = "/Subcription/Index/";
           jQuery.get(url, { id: client }, function (data) {
               $("#divpart").empty();
               $("#divpart").append(data);
           });
```

Comment: that i dont know as i have imlemented my personal error message

Comment: IF you change to hard code the domain, does it work?  Example: `http://www.example.com/Subcription/Index/`

Comment: I have changed that and still has the same issue that when the code is called to edit the data the data is saved and changed but when the data is called to create a new object it fails, but the code for the edit and create is the same and on  the local mathcine it works fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your application has a context-root on the server side. Since you are using the initial slash "/", the URL is an absolute URL and your context-root will be removed.

For instance if the valid URL on the server is something like this

```
http://your.domain.com/yourapplication/Subcription/Index/
```

Your call will result in something different:

```
http://your.domain.com/Subcription/Index/
```

Comment: but when i am editing the data on the server the data is saved.. but when I am save as create the system fails..